# Remove div on changing the radio button

Tags: javascript

There are two radio buttons. (Javascript)Upon selecting 1st option the div class must be removed which is in another page and upon selecting 2nd option the div must be shown and this execution should happen only after clicking on submit button. 
Any help highly appreciated.

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">Regular Shipping
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2">COD Shopping

<input type="submit" class="btn" value="SUBMIT">

<!----------The following div is in another page------>

<div class="test">Lorem Ipusm</div>
```

Comment: so, you submit the form, and based on the value of your radio-group, you either want to show or not a div?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What did you mean by _another page_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below solution:

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', change_value);
function change_value(){
  var radioOptions = document.getElementsByName('radio');
  var selected = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < radioOptions.length; i++) {       
      if (radioOptions[i].checked) {
          selected = radioOptions[i].id
          break;
      }
  }
  if(selected == 'radio1'){
    document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].style.display = 'none';
  } else if (selected == 'radio2'){
    document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    alert('select option first!');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">Regular Shipping
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2">COD Shopping

<input type="submit" id='submit' class="btn" value="SUBMIT">

<!----------The following div is in another page------>

<div class="test">Lorem Ipusm</div>
```

In above code I just hidden/display the first element with className is 'test', incase you want to apply for all, you need a loop to do it.

Comment: Mark as answer if it's helpful.